# React - State Hook map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I know there are similar questions, but I can't find out why the error happens. Div shows, but then app crashes (as if was some length problem)

Code is similar to examples I found, like this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/93456l21np)

What am I doing wrong?

this is component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
/* import Button from '../Button' */
import { getPlanets } from '../../services/index'
import './Planetas.css'


const Planetas = () => {

    const [planetas, setPlanetas] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPlanetas = async () => {
            const planetas = await getPlanets()
            setPlanetas({ planetas })
        };    
        fetchPlanetas()
    }, []);


    return (
      <div className="planetas">
      {
        planetas.map((planeta, key) => {
            return <div key={key}>{planeta.name}</div>
        })
      }
      </div>
    )
}

export default Planetas
```

this is api service:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const BASE_URL = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets'

export const getPlanets = async() => {
    const planets = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}`).catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
    })
    console.log('resp\n')
    console.log(planets.data.results)

    return planets.data.results
}
```

error:

[image]

Comment: `map` is array function not `object`. and I think your `planetas` is object.

Comment: are fetiching your **planetas** from other api, if yes than use **{planetas && planetas.map((planeta, key) => {** to check and wait until u are getting the value of planetas

Answer (score 11, accepted):

setPlanetas({ planetas }) in this line you're setting your state to be an object with a `planetas` property, instead you need to do `setPlanetas(planetas)`

Answer (score 3):

you have `planetas` state which is `array` data types but when you update `planetas` state you updated state with curly braces outside response array i.e `setPlanetas({ planetas })` instead of `setPlanetas(planetas)`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchPlanetas = async () => {
            const planetas = await getPlanets()
            setPlanetas(planetas) // remove curly braces here
        };    
        fetchPlanetas()
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I used:

```
Object.values(array).map()
```

It worked for me. I hope help somebody else.

Comment: Your answer is also correct, but it would be helpful and good practice to add some explanation about what code is doing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Need an array here to map. => setPlanetas(planetas).